How to view logs of deleted folders
2 days ago I edited some files on my iMac. I came back today and inexplicably there was no folder containing those files.
I would like to know how to view reports of files deleted during this sort of time range.
Does macOS have logs of deletions that are time stamped?

There are no file system logs for file deletion. What is easy is to set up Time Machine and if you have the default hourly snapshots, you can isolate when the files went missing as well as which time they were present.
Sorry I’m not able to pinpoint things better unless you already has backup configured or your machine was making APFS snapshots already.

https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/view-apfs-snapshots-dskuf82354dc/mac

You can look for snapshots using disk utility, perhaps you get lucky with some made during this time interval?
